# Why do some forms suddenly lose functionality?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

once in a while in this application I have been working on a form will suddenly lose all of it's functionality with the database and I am forced to erase all of the work I have done on it and completely re-build it.

For instance adding a new entry to the database; I can hit Add New which calls bindingsource.addnew() enter all of the required information into the text boxes, hit save then when I close and re-open the form nothing is displayed in the datagrid.  If I go directly to the table in the SQL Database nothing has been added here either?

It seems to escalate suddenly, when I edit an entry in a table then save it it does not update.  After that I cannot add rows to it but it will let me delete rows and save that?

```
Tablename.bindingsource.addnew()

Tablename.bindingsource.endedit()
Tablename.tableadapter.update(datasetname.tablename)
```

This is what I have used for adding rows and saving new entries plus edits to the data source for some time now.  Is there something I need to be watching out for otherwise?

```
Private Sub createnew()
    '' CREATE AND SAVE NEW ENTRY
    CalibratedEquipmentBindingSource.AddNew()
    dateaddedlbl.Text = datelbl.Text
    CalibratedEquipmentBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Calibrated_EquipmentTableAdapter.Update(MacroQualityDataSet.Calibrated_Equipment)
End Sub

Private Sub savebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles savebtn.Click

    Try
        Dim accountname As String = "macroqc"
        Dim acocuntkey As String = My.Settings.Storagekey1

        Dim creds As StorageCredentials = New StorageCredentials(accountname, acocuntkey)
        Dim account As CloudStorageAccount = New CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps:=True)

        Dim client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient()

        Dim container As CloudBlobContainer = client.GetContainerReference(My.Settings.smallequipmentcertscontainername)
        container.CreateIfNotExists()

        Dim blob As CloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(My.Settings.ticketsource)
        Using FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(My.Settings.ticketsource)
            blob.UploadFromStream(FileStream)
            filenamelbl.Text = My.Settings.ticketsource

            '' GET HTTPS: PATH OF BLOB
            ''blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri & blob.Uri.AbsolutePath

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry an error has occured while uploading your file: " & Environment.NewLine & ex.ToString, "Upload Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    If datelbl.Text.Length > 3 Then
        dateeditedlbl.Text = datelbl.Text
    End If

    CalibratedEquipmentBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Calibrated_EquipmentTableAdapter.Update(MacroQualityDataSet.Calibrated_Equipment)
    gridcolors()
    MsgBox("Save Complete!")
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It's impossible for us to debug code we can't see, and the three lines you've posted are not sufficient to reproduce the problem. You have the source available, and can use that to debug. We can't see it or read your screen from where we are. You're going to need to be a whole lot more specific about the problem if you expect help here. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ken I have posted the code for the entire form to which I am referring.  The newbtn references createnew which is supposed to add a new row then immediately save it then the user adds information and saves it as an update.  As I said previously this was working completely fine before, and it suddenly just quit.  Is there any reason which jumps out at you by chance?

Comment: I have deleted everything that is irrelevant to adding a new row and saving that information.  I only came here and asked this for help, clearly I do not know what I am Looking for or I would not be asking this question.  Two of my recent threads Ken you have been benighted and picked my questions apart. I'm sorry that the way I asked my question was not up to your standards. I would rather just re-build it than bicker with you on here.  Ta Ta